# WP - child theme get the theme directory

Tags: wordpress, wordpress-theming

I have an image folder in a child directory where some theme-related gfx is located. If I want to access it via:

```
<img src="<?php echo get_template_directory_uri();?>/assets/Logo.svg" />
```

It's trying to look for /assets in the parent theme directory.

How can I reference the child theme directory?

Comment: instead of `get_template_directory_uri` use [`get_stylesheet_directory_uri`](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/get_stylesheet_directory_uri/) function:

Comment: @SamvelAleqsanyan as much as that is short and sweat is is also the exact correct answer. You should post such an answer so we can mark this as solved for future askers and searchers :)

Answer (score 3):

The function [`get_template_directory_uri`](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/get_template_directory_uri/) always return the url of Parent Theme. Don't matter, where you called it.

To get the url of your Child Theme, you can use [`get_stylesheet_directory_uri()`](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/get_stylesheet_directory_uri/). So, your code will be:

```
<img src="<?php echo get_stylesheet_directory_uri();?>/assets/Logo.svg" />
```